# How to prove that $p_{n+1}p_{n+2}p_{n+3}>p_{n+4}p_{n+5}$?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, conjectures, maximal-and-prime-ideals

$p_n$ is the $n$-th prime number: If $n > 3$ then:

$$p_{n + 1} p_{n + 2} p_{n + 3} > p_{n + 4} p_{n + 5}$$

I checked the conjecture above true for [first fifty million primes](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/).

If the conjecture above is true, it is stronger than [Bonse's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonse%27s_inequality).

> Could you give your remark, reference, or your proof of conjecture above?

Comment: Bertrand's postulate and its cousins might help here.

Comment: Very good, I think your ideas to prove that is true.

Comment: Dear @Arthur thank to You very much, there is very weaker inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonse%27s_inequality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Pierre Dusart's paper [arXiv:1002.0442](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0442) (page 2) we know that
$$
p_k \le k \left(\log k + \log\log k - 1 + {\log\log k - 2\over \log k}\right) \qquad\mbox{ for } k\ge 688383,
\tag{1}
$$
$$
p_k \ge k \left(\log k + \log\log k - 1 + {\log\log k - 2.1\over \log k}\right) \qquad\mbox{ for } k\ge 3. \ \ \quad
\tag{2}
$$
Substituting the lower bound $(2)$ for primes in the left-hand side, 
and upper bound $(1)$ for primes in the right-hand side, we prove the desired inequality for 
$k\ge 688383$.

For smaller $k$, the inequality can be verified directly by computer.

Comment: These inequalities have been improved just two days ago on arXiv :P  https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03651

Comment: Very good result

Answer (score 3):

After noting that $2\cdot3\cdot5\lt7\cdot11$ and $3\cdot5\cdot7\lt11\cdot13$, the inequality to prove can be written as

$$p_np_{n+1}p_{n+2}\gt p_{n+3}p_{n+4}\quad\text{for }n\ge3$$

It suffices to check that $5\cdot7\cdot11\gt13\cdot17$ and $7\cdot11\cdot13\gt17\cdot19$ and then show that

$$p_n^3\gt p_{n+4}^2\quad\text{for }n\ge5$$

By Bertrand's Postulate, we have $p_{n+4}\lt2p_{n+3}\lt4p_{n+2}\lt8p_{n+1}\lt16p_n$, hence $p_{n+4}^2\lt256p_n^2$, and so the inequality certainly holds as soon as $p_n\gt256$.  To dispense with the smaller cases, it suffices to note that $256^2\lt41^3$, $53^2\lt19^3$, and $31^2\lt11^3$ (where $53$ is the third prime after $41$ and $31$ is the third prime after $19$).

Answer (score 2):

In 2011, [Andy Loo](http://www.m-hikari.com/ijcms-2011/37-40-2011/looIJCMS37-40-2011.pdf) proved that there exists a prime $p_k$ between $3n$ and $4n$. Therefore there exists another prime $\ge p_{k+1}$ between $4n$ and $\frac{4}{3}4n<6n$, so that 
$$
p_{k+1} \le \frac{6n}{3n}p_k \le 2p_k \implies p_{k+2}\le 4p_k.
$$

It follows that if $p_{n+1}\ge 17$ then
$$
p_{n+1}\,\frac{p_{n+2}}{p_{n+4}}\, \frac{p_{n+3}}{p_{n+5}}\ge \frac{p_{n+1}}{16}>1.
$$

Comment: I'm not sure why you need Loo's result, when Bertrand's postulate (i.e., there exists a prime strictly between $x$ and $2x$ for every $x>1$) is sufficient: $$p_{k+1}<2p_k\Rightarrow p_{k+2}<4p_k\Rightarrow \frac{p_{n+1}p_{n+2}p_{n+3}}{p_{n+4}p_{n+5}}>\frac{p_{n+1}}{16}>1$$ for $p_{n+1}\geq 17$.

Answer (score 1):

In general the primes are close enough together that the left-hand side will be a bit larger than $p_n^3$ and the right-hand  side will be a bit larger than $p_n^2$.  So if your inequality fails anywhere it will fail for small values of $p_n$ (or, equivalent, for small values of $n$).  Thus we take a two-pronged strategy: first we'll use inequalities that are known to hold for the primes to derive your inequality when $n$ is large, and then we check explicitly when $n$ is small.

In particular we'll use Bertrand's postulate, which states that $p_{n+1} < 2p_n$, for any $n$.  In particular we can turn this around to get $p_{n+1} > p_{n+4}/8, p_{n+2} > p_{n+4}/4, p_{n+3} > p_{n+4}/2$, and so we have

$$ p_{n+1} p_{n+2} p_{n+3} > p_{n+4}^3 / 64. $$

So to show the desired inequality it suffices to show that $p_{n+4}^3 / 64 > p_{n+4} p_{n+5}$, i. e. that $p_{n+4}^2 > 64 p_{n+5}$.  We have $p_{n+4} > p_{n+5}/2$.  Therefore $p_{n+4}^2 > p_{n+5}^2 / 4$.  So if we have $p_{n+5}^2 / 4 > 64 p_{n+5}$, then your inequality holds.  Rearranging gives $p_{n+5} > 256$.  So your inequality holds if $p_{n+5} > 256$.

If $p_{n+5} \le 256$, you can just check directly, as you already have - observe that $5 \times 7 \times 11 > 13 \times 17$, $7 \times 11 \times 13 > 17 \times 19$, and so on up to $229 \times 233 \times 239 > 241 \times 251$.

Answer (score 0):

My prove by ideas of Dr. Arthu, Apply [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate)

We have:

$P_{n+4}P_{n+5}<2P_{n+4}^2<8P_{n+3}^2$

But $8P_{n+3}^2<P_{n+1}P_{n+2}P_{n+3}$ when $8P_{n+3}<P_{n+1}P_{n+2}$.

We have:

$8P_{n+3}<16P_{n+2}$

When $P_{n+1}>16$, inequality (1) is true, whith $n>6$, we can check direct with $n=4,5$